# Group product in Aluffi's book

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

In his book, first encounter of a groups has the following: Define group as a groupoid with a single object. Define category Grp in such a way that objects are $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ for any group $G$, and morphisms are such that preserves the structure. Then he define a direct product of a group by stating an universal property: given any groups $X$, $A$, $B$ we have a unique morphism $f\colon X\to A\times B$ defined as follows: $f(x) := (a(x),b(x))$, which indeed makes a diagram with two morphisms $a\colon X \to A$ and $b\colon X \to B$ commute.

My question is: what is the formal definition of an ordered pair here? We are not working in set theory, so obviously we can't take $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ as the notion (moreover since not all morphisms will be "small enough" to be a sets, so we can have a singleton of it. So what is an ordered pair then? I searched through nlab, and it says that ordered pair is basically an object of a product in category theory, but we use it to define product then, which is cyclic.

Comment: Groups are small categories. Because typically the definition of a category requires $hom(X,Y)$ to be a set. Either way: what exactly is the problem in defining pair in the usual way? Just because it is category theory, it doesn't mean you cannot use sets.

Comment: To elaborate: the product $A\times B$ (thinking of this as a [product of categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+category)) has one object (also referred to as $A\times B$) and a single homset $\mathrm{Hom}(A\times B, A\times B)$ which is given by the set-theoretic product $\mathrm{Hom}(A,A)\times\mathrm{Hom}(B,B)$. Ordered pairs as we usually describe them in set theory work perfectly fine.

Comment: Who told you we weren't working in set theory? I would argue that "most" category theory happens internal to ZFC (probably with large cardinal axioms).

Comment: Aluffi absolutely works in set theory throughout all of Chapter 0.

Comment: @freakish I disagree that typically categories require $\text{Hom}(X, Y)$ to be a set.  Most standard texts, Aluffi included, do not make this assumption.  That's why the terminology "locally small category" exists.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Aluffi says in definition I.3.1 that he isn't working in set theory.  While he mentions large cardinal axioms (which are not internal to ZFC) he ultimately opts for using classes, which is the norm.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Your claim is false, as I mentioned above, he explicitly states that he uses classes, and many examples require proper classes.

Comment: @KristapsJohnBalodis yeah, the term exists, but in practice almost all categories are locally small. In fact I saw it being included in the definition of category more often than not. But that doesn't really matter, since the ordered pair can be defined regardless of whether it is a set or not.

Comment: @KristapsJohnBalodis: Nothing that you wrote contradicts my claim that Aluffi works in set theory throughout all of Chapter 0.

Comment: @KristapsJohnBalodis -- in definition I.3.1 Aluffi never says that he's not working in set theory. He mentions that certain categories aren't sets, instead they're either proper classes or "small sets" relative to a universe (read: large cardinal). But both mentioned solutions (classes and cardinals) _are part of the subject of set theory_.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that as Aluffi states in the book, the definition of a group as a groupoid with a single object is a *joke*.  Of course, he himself mentions, the "joke definition" is valid, and a reasonable way to think about groups, but you're better off taking a more "down to earth" approach first.  Namely, use Definition II.1.2 which Aluffi calls the "official" definition. Thus, everything in Chapter II should be taken with respect to Definition II.1.2, the official definition.

Note, the joke definition subsumes, and is strictly more general than the official definition, precisely because we're not restricted to sets.

Likewise, Aluffi does not technically define group products by first stating a universal property.  Rather, he first defines product of groups in the traditional set-theoretic sense after Proposition II.3.3, and then in Proposition II.3.4 he demonstrates that the set-theoretic product he defined satisfies the universal property of products as discussed in I.5.4.
Moreover, as I mentioned above, Aluffi is working with Definition II.1.2 as his definition of group, and therefore it is a set, and ordered pairs make sense.

Of course this still leaves open the question of how to define a product of *groupoids* more abstractly.  Though the objects and morphisms of an arbitrary category may not be sets, they are still a *class*.  In this case, one can still form ordered pairs of classes in much the same way one does for sets.  From there, one defines products of categories as mentioned in the comment by freakish, and ultimately groupoids, following the same process.